# django - create user from request

Tags: django, forms, request, admin

I need some help with django request
I want to add a custom form proccessing to add a user (or any other model instance)

I don't want to create it like this

```
tagName = request.POST["tagname"]
        new_tag = Tag()
        new_tag.name = tagName
        new_tag.save()
```

because I would need to rewrite this code everythime something changes in the model
Is there any way how can I create a model instance from the request?
What is the way django-admin do this?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/)